# How to handle the situation of saving to Elasticsearch logs whose structure are very diverse?

Tags: elasticsearch

My log POCO has several fixed properties, like user id, timestamp, with a flexible data bag property, which is a JSON representation of any kind of extra information I'd like to add to the log. This means the property names could be anything within this data bag, bringing me 2 questions:

1. How can I configure the mapping so that the data bag property, which is of type string, would be mapped to a JSON object during the indexing, instead of being treated as a normal string?
2. With the data bag object having arbitrary property names, meaning the overall document type could have a huge number of properties inside, would this hurt the search performance?

Comment: does the data bag object change in size? eg it might be N for this event, N+2 for the next one

Comment: @MarkWalkom Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by 'change in size'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the data translation from string to JSON you can use ingest pipeline with JSON processor:
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/json-processor.html
2. It depends of you queries. If you'll use the "free text search" - yes, the huge number of fields will slow the query. If you you'll use query like "field":"value" - no, there is no problem with the fields number in the searches. Additional information about query optimization you cold find here:
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/tune-for-search-speed.html#search-as-few-fields-as-possible

And the question is: what you meen, when say "huge number"? 1000? 10000? 100000? As part of optimization i recommend to use dynamic templates with the definition: each string field automatically ingest into the index as "keyword" and not text + keyword. This setting decrease the number of fields to half.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the JSON processor. For the second issue, I believe the [flattened datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html) looks to be the solution. Still working on the learning this guy.

Comment: The problem of "flattened" type - impossibility to do free search without regex, and regex very expensive in the Elasticsearch.. but as regular -depends of use case

Comment: After some considerations, I decided to use two different POCO types, with no systematic parent/child relationship nor flattened typing, to solve my case. I'd rotate the dynamic object so that the unknown number of fields turn to any number of document with simple name/value fields, and link them with some sort of id.